# How to display images from api using handlebars in Pure js ? base64

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars template to display the data. Now I am retrieving using url to display the image. I don't know how to retrieve the image using base64. How can retrieve using base64.

```
{{#each content.files }}
        <img class="mb-4 src="{{this.url}}" />
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 {{#each content.files}}
        <img class="mb-4 src="data:image/png;base64, {{image}}" />
   {{/each}}
```